# what is the replacement for deprecated Input Method?

Tags: android

Right now I am doing an assignment in Android Studio with minSdkVersion 16.
I want to set only NUMERIC KEYPAD to my "edittext " .For this i got search results as "need to use android:INPUT TYPE=NUMBER" ,but input type is not there in my edit text attributes,only Input Method which was deprecated.

Could someone suggests solution for the issue.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Have you looked at the Android Developer site My question to you are you trying to set the keyboard or limit the input to NUMBERS only

Comment: android:inputType="number". it is not deprecated. It is working for me. :)